# Point-Line shortest distance and corresponding angle using FME

Tags: point, distance, line, angles, fme-form

I want to determine the shortest distance and especially the corresponding angle from a point to a polyline. A solution using FME would be strongly preferred.

[image]

Comment: Neighbor-finder Transformer https://www.safe.com/transformers/neighbor-finder/

Comment: NeighborFinder matches features based on their proximity > Tutorial https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/23302/passing-attributes-between-features-in-close-proxi.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does the trick. Must have been blind when reading my transformer reference guide...